# using jq to split huge json UNDER windows

Tags: json, jq

i want to use jq to split a very large json (>80GB) file into smaller parts (<1GB or a fixed number of lines). 
I have the necessary statements together... I thought.
What do I do so far?

```
jq ". | length" z:\DOWNLOAD\rows.json
```

works!

Under Windows this should output the first two lines.

```
jq ".[0:1]" z:\DOWNLOAD\rows.json
```

but I'm getting an error

> jq: error (at z:\DOWNLOAD\rows.json:589): Cannot index object with
>   object

What I also haven't understood the --Steam switch

yes, there are a bunch [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808581/using-jq-how-can-i-split-a-very-large-json-file-into-multiple-files-each-a-spec), but they do not work under windows (double quotes instead of apostrophe, but see error above)

```
[{"node":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q952111","Unterklasse_von":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2095"},{"node":"http://.....
```

Comment: Since `jq length` works, `jq type` should also work and may explain why you are seeing the reported error.  Also, since `jq length` works, chances are you won't need the --stream option, but it would probably be helpful to see a snippet that's representative of your JSON.

Comment: You may use `split` command to get it done.  Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609650/how-to-split-file-in-windows-just-like-linux

Comment: this splitting does not respect the structure of a json file. the splitting is done line by line. this may only work with jsonl files. but unfortunately the file is not a.... ;-(