# How to copy a section of XML file and create a new file using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a file with 250,000 lines.

I want to copy the first 65,000 into file 1 and remaining into other file. How can I do this with Notepad++? is there any plugin to do this?

Comment: I would recommend another tools instead of Notepadd++. And asking for plugins or this kind of stuff is off topic here. Here is an answer that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34609796/460557

Comment: Found a way to do it in notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In notepad++:

1. Press Ctrl + G, type the start line and hit Enter to go to the start line.
2. Then go to the menu, click on Edit and then Begin/End select.
3. Press again Ctrl + G, and type the end line number and hit Enter to go to it.
4. Back to the menu, click on Edit and then Begin/End select once more.
5. By now you will have your range of lines selected. Copy the highlighted section and paste it in the new file.

Thanks to this website link: https://bytefreaks.net/applications/notepad/select-range-of-lines-in-notepad-using-line-numbers/amp